# Split DATETIME in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have datetime (`5/24/2013`)
I want to split them into 3 strings like

I need CODES from VB.NET

```
String 1 = 5
String 2 = 24 
String 3 = 2013
```

Comment: Is this stored as a date or string in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate [`DateTime` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime_properties.aspx):

```
Dim value As New DateTime(2013, 5, 24)
Dim dayString As String = value.Day.ToString()
Dim monthString As String = value.Month.ToString()
Dim yearString As String = value.Year.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is a string, you have to parse it first:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("5/24/2013", "d", Nothing)
Dim day As String = dt.Day.ToString()
Dim month As String = dt.Month.ToString()
Dim year As String = dt.Year.ToString()
```

Comment: He has mentioned twice that it's a `DateTime` not a string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not sure he meant a type. He said "the 5/24/2013 is from database" so I assume he is getting it as a string

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method

```
dim dbDate1 as Date 
dim string1 as string
dim string2 as string
dim string3 as string
dim number1 as integer
dim number2 as integer
dim number3 as integer

' Strings
string1 = dbDate1.Day().ToString()
string2 = dbDate1.Month().ToString()
string3 = dbDate1.Year().ToString()
```

and if you wanted a number instead of a string simply remove the ".ToString()" from the end of the line

```
' Numbers
number1 = dbDate1.Day()
number2 = dbDate1.Month()
number3 = dbDate1.Year()
```

It should work the same whether your data is DATE or DATETIME object